# For x in list and list.insert causes endless loop

Tags: python-2.7

I have no idea if this is a bug or not, but why does this cause an endless loop?

```
>>> top_ports = [[1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]]
>>> a = 2
>>> for x in top_ports:
...     if a > x[0]:
...             top_ports.insert(0,a)
...
```

Comment: `print x`, you will know why. BTW, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, you are inserting new items inside your list that is currently under looping processing .. you have to change your code to be like the following

```
>>> result = []
>>> top_ports = [[1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]]
>>> a = 2
>>> for x in top_ports:
...     if a > x[0]:
...             result.insert(0,a)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`x` represents the iterated element inside `top_ports`. But when `a > x[0]` is `true`, an element is added to `top_ports`:

```
top_ports.insert(0,a)
```

So because the length of `top_ports` continuously increases, the for loop never terminates.

You could also check this by being more verbose. Printing `x` always yields `[1]` in your example. This is because as the loop continues to execute, `a` is always being adding, like this:

```
[2, 2, 2, ... [1], [0.9], [0.8], [0.7], [0.6]]
```

The for loop is never really able to jump to the next element because the values also move one further element away.

Hope this helps you!