# Inserting into parent node (Module body) while using Python AST NodeTransformer triggering infinite recursion

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to learn about AST and NodeTransformer through this hypothetical case:

*Replace the keywords 'elif/else' while still ensuring the program output remains the same. *

My approach is to use introduce a temporary variable for the if 'block' and test this to determine if the 'elif/else' parts for the block should be executed.

e.g. Given:

```
code='''
if a:
    print (True)
else:
    print (False) 
'''
```

The transformed code is:

```
_boolIf0 = False
if a:
    _boolIf0 = True
    print (True)
if _boolIf0 == False
    print (False)
```

I created class ParentLinks to populate the 'parent' attribute for every node in the tree. I then created sub-class ReplaceElse to make updates to a node's ('If' in our example) parent (or any other ancestor). As a first step, I simply want to introduce this temp variable at the right place in the AST.

```
class ParentLinks(ast.NodeTransformer):
    parent = None    
    def visit(self, node):
        node.parent = self.parent
        self.parent = node
        node = super().visit(node)
        if isinstance(node, ast.AST):
            self.parent = node.parent
        return node

class ReplaceElse(ParentLinks):                

    def visit_If(self, node: ast.If):        
        
        super().generic_visit(node) #Visit child nodes
 
        #Create a temp variable for current If block in the form of an assign node  
        temp_var_id = f'_booIf{node.col_offset}'
        assign_if_node = ast.Assign(
                targets=[ast.Name(id=temp_var_id, ctx=ast.Store())],
                value=ast.Constant(value=False)
            )
        
        p = node.parent #Get the parent of the current If node
               
        if isinstance(p, ast.Module): #Parent is the module
            pos = p.body.index (node)      #Find the index of current node in the module (0 in our example)
            
            #Insert the assign node at that index 
            p.body = [assign_if_node] + p.body
            #p.body.insert(pos, assign_if_node) #Triggers infinite recursion
                        
            #ast.increment_lineno(node, n=1)
            #ast.fix_missing_locations(node)
        else:
            ... #Extra logic for other types of parents
        return node

tree = ast.parse(code)
print(ast.dump(tree, indent='   '))
new_tree = ReplaceElse().visit(tree)
new_tree = ast.fix_missing_locations(new_tree)
print(ast.dump(new_tree, indent='   '))
print(ast.unparse(new_tree)) #Print transformed code
```

I tried 2 ways of inserting a node in the Module body.

`p.body.insert(pos, assign_if_node) #Triggers infinite recursion`

Using ast.increment_lineno and ast.fix_missing_locations(node) did not help.

`p.body = [assign_if_node] + p.body #This seems to work`

So, what is the correct way of updating a node which is **not** the current node being visited by NodeTransformer? Can these other nodes even be updated in this way, and if not, how can this be done?

Edit: I'm using Python 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach using `p.body.insert` approach did exactly what you told it to do, however the default `NodeTransformer` visitor does not track whether or not the current node that's being visited is has inserted a new node *before* the current node, so the underlying `for` loop (via the internal [`iter_fields`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/ast.py#L257-L266), used by [`NodeTransformer.generic_visit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/ast.py#L477-L497)), will not realize that a new element that has inserted before the current node so the loop never advances, and this in fact [results in an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283909/for-x-in-list-and-list-insert-causes-endless-loop) (**not** infinite recursion).

A naive method for naive visitors under this approach will be to simply figure out a way to mark visited nodes and not process them, but this potentially have unwanted side-effects or additional memory usage.

Your second approach using `p.body = [assign_if_node] + p.body` fails to trigger the infinite loop error is simply because this approach replaced the original with a new assignment that includes the `assign_if_node`, all the while the iterator in the visitor is still referencing the initial input, thus no new elements will be presented to the iterator that would extend what it was looking at. (Also this approach only prepends all the assignments, and does not put the assignment immediately before the `if` block, differing to the `body.insert` approach being taken.)

The correct method is to check how the visitor should be used and use it as documented - the [`ast.NodeTransformer` documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) that its intended usage is that it will "use the return value of the visitor methods to replace or remove the old node", and that "the visitor may also return a list of nodes" whenever the nodes "were part of a collection of statements".  So taking that into account, this is what should be done:

```
class ReplaceElse(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_If(self, node: ast.If):
        super().generic_visit(node)
        temp_var_id = f'_booIf{node.col_offset}'
        assign_if_node = ast.Assign(
            targets=[ast.Name(id=temp_var_id, ctx=ast.Store())],
            value=ast.Constant(value=False),
        )
        return [
            assign_if_node,
            node,
        ]
```

Noticed how this example does not manually manipulate its parent, but rather simply return a list with the new `ast.Assign` node before the provided node, which is what the original code in the question should have done (though it does not achieve the desired output, as the code for that was not provided with the question).

Comment: OK, makes sense. Would you mind explaining why the below works as it seems to be doing the same thing: _p.body = [assign_if_node] + p.body_ as the insert to the parent body. I'm checking the transformed code using: _print(ast.unparse(new_tree)). Also, if I **did**_ need to insert something at a specific location in a parent (rather than just before the current node as we're doing here), how would we achieve that?

Comment: See modification.

Comment: As for insertion to a specific location, you might use a second visitor to visit the parent node(s) rather and it should return specific information that would allow the insertion of the relevant nodes at the parent if you want to use the `NodeTransformer` the way it's intended to, otherwise what you've done is not much different than using to using the `NodeVisitor` as all you did was to return the original input node.